# Contract deploy failed. Caused by Gas is insufficient. Can add more Gas and re-deploy again?

Tags: gas

In fact got 3 question to ask:

1. when using Mist to deploy a contract (link testnet), why i always need to add more GAS, so that 
   my contract could deploy successfully. otherwise, usually deploy failed.
   (failed contract seems cannot be review,no detail,and cannot do anything....)
   see graphic bellow~(no data created on address...)
   [image]
2. And  if the contract deploy failed, why cannot re-deploy the contract and add more gas to make it works ?  
   update:
   failed type such as 1. metioned.... seems create address succeed ,but no data in it....looks like no any way to do re-deploy...
3. Can delete the failed contract on Mist?  since it is unable to be used.
   update:
   i find every deploy succeed contract,in contract itself detail veiw 
   at the contract name right side , provide a hidden trachcan icon to delete it..
   but deploy failed ones ,cannot find any function to do delete...

Answer (score 1):

1. There are some design patterns for smart contracts to be followed to have the less gas usage. You can check your contract's estimated gas in browser solidity remix. If you check in that you see gas limit around that. Otherwise, if you deploy the contract using the solc compiler, the deployed object will also have the details needed.
   https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/
2. Deploy failed means it is not added to the blockchain, contract address is not created. So you can add gas and deploy. Once all the required gas limit available then the contract is added to the blockchain network
3. Yes, Of Course, you can delete the failed contracts on mist because it could not be used anymore.